# When you divide a hexadecimal, what do you get?

Tags: c, hex

I'm trying to create a hash function which stores hexadecimals but I'm not to sure what the hash function to be. I get the addresses which are hexadecimals from a text file and then convert them into unsigned long long int. I'm trying to create a hash table of size 1000, so what exactly do I get when I divide these long long ints? I don't exactly understand this.

The input file contains lines like this:

```
0x7f1a91026b00
0x7f1a91026b03
0x7f1a91027130
0x7f1a91027131
0x7f1a91027134
0x7f1a91027136
```

Here's my code so far (I have not created the hash table at the moment since I don't have the hash function)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv){

    if(argc!=2){
        printf("error\n");
        return 0;
        // if there is no input then print an error
    }

    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r"); // open file

    if (!file){
        printf("error\n");
        return 0;
    }

    char linestring[BUFSIZ];

    while (fgets(linestring, sizeof(linestring), file)) // reads the entire file until it hits Null
    {
        char *endptr;
        unsigned long long key = strtoull(linestring, &endptr, 16);

        printf("%s\n", linestring);
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense, there is no difference between **hex** or **decimal** except for the representation which in the end will be **binary**, think of this `int x = 0x04; int y = x / 2; printf("%d\n", y);` what's the output?

Comment: @iharob but lets say i have "7f1a91027130" , im not sure what dividing it by a certain number will get me.

Comment: It will give you the result of the mathematical division, i think..

Comment: sorry if i am confusing, im taking computer architecture atm, and this isnt for homework but i am just trying to figure out how this actually works.

Comment: If i want to make a hash function for this, i want the output to be less than 1000. so how can i tell if dividing that hex by a certain number will give me less than 1000? Thats what im trying to figure out which i cant tell by looking at it

Comment: @Saiyed: You can either have your program tell you the answer, or you can convert that number to a decimal representation and do the division in base-10 where you are comfortable (on paper, with a calculator, etc.) and then convert the answer back to its hexadecimal representation.

Comment: Representing a number in hexadecimal is not turning it into something magical. It is remaining the same number. So if you are feeling better with decimals, convert the number to decimal first, and divide it.

Comment: @Saiyed: If you want the answer to be less than 1000 then you can use the modulus operator % to achieve that: (expression) % 1000.  However, you probably want to work with multiples of 2 instead (e.g. - 1024) since that is the base in which computers are "most comfortable" and %'s can be converted to simple bit masks, multiplication and division can be converted to simple shift left and shift rights, etc.

Comment: Your hex numbers are large, but they are just ordinary numbers: `0x7f1a91027130` is the same as `139752078733616`.  If you divide, or better take the remainder of the division by say `1000`, you will get `616`.  This is simplistic way to dispatch numbers in 1000 buckets.  If the numbers are random, they will dispatch somewhat evenly.  Alas real world data is not random, so a simplistic hash function might not scatter them usefully

Comment: Awesome this is exactly what i needed! Thanks guy, i understand how these are done now and why % would work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hexadecimal, Decimal and Octal are simply 3 different ways of **printing to the screen** the same number.

Let's look at the number **100**. We could print it in decimal as `100`. Similarly, we could print it in octal as `0144`. And we could print it in hexadecimal as `0x64`.

But all three of those represent the same number. So the result of `100 / 3`, `0144 / 3`, and `0x64 / 3` are all **identical**.

#### Onto your real question...

You have a number `x`. You'd like to restrict `x` to be a number between `[0, 0x1000)`. The easiest way to do that is to do:

```
unsigned long long x;
unsigned long long y = x % 0x1000;
```

Now y will be within the range of `[0, 0x1000)`. This is basically accomplished by subtracting `0x1000` from `x` until it is less than `0x1000`.

Comment: And the same for input. The file contains hexadecimal numbers, but once read to a variable, they are the same internally as all other ways of representing them for human consumption.

Comment: Maybe change "printing to the screen" and "print" to "represent"?

Comment: i think he meant 1000 in decimal

Comment: @gio: I'd like to believe that someone can read this, and be able to replace `0x1000` with any number, and understand that `0x1000` isn't special.

Comment: @BillLynch: yeah you are right, although it is bit confusing seems he just wanted to know how to get numbers in range [0,1000)- for which he needn't even post the code

Comment: This discards the highest part of the number, similar to (in hex) `x & 0xFFFF`. For a good spread, shouldn't you rather propose the decimal equivalent of `((x >> 16) ^ x) & 0xFFFF`?

Answer (score 0):

So if you want hash table size of 1000 then you need to get the modulo of 0x3E8 so for example 0x7f1a91026b00 % 0x3e8 = 0x20. This represent the 32 in dec.

Hex 0x3e8 = Dec 1000.

Comment: In C, you need to precede those numbers by "0x".  In particular, 3e8, not preceded by 0x, will be interpreted as the double = 3.0 * 10^8.